# Question about definition of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

By the definition from the book of Kenneth Rosen, we know that a graph consists of a nonempty set of vertices and a set E of edges. Each edges has either one or two vertices associated with it, called its endpoints. An edge is said to connect its endpoints.

From his definition, does it literally mean we actually can form a graph for which the edge has only one vertice on it?

Comment: I think that would be a loop (an edge going back to connect with the same vertex).

Comment: oh i see. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. These so-called loops do indeed have some significant meaning. For example, given a planar graph, the [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) can contain loops (even if the planar graph was without loops). It is also interesting for the [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) of graphs, see e.g. [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0012365X18300311).